# Series Expansion Using Results from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, functions, series-expansion

I have a list of relations from using the Reduce function and I want to use them to get a series expansion in each variable. Here's what my relations look like:

```
a[1] != 0 && (a[2] == Root[a[1]^2 + #1^2 + a[1] #1^3 &, 1] || 
   a[2] == Root[a[1]^2 + #1^2 + a[1] #1^3 &, 2] || 
   a[2] == Root[a[1]^2 + #1^2 + a[1] #1^3 &, 3]) && 
 a[3] == a[2] (1/a[1] + a[2]) && a[1] a[2] == a[4] && a[2]^2 == a[5] &&
  a[6] == 0 && a[2] a[3] == a[7] && a[1] a[3] + a[8] == a[2] a[4] && 
 a[1] a[4] + a[2] (-a[3] + a[5]) + a[4] a[7] + a[5] a[8] == a[9] && 
 a[2] != 0 && (a[1] a[3])/a[2] + a[10] == 0 && 
 a[1]^2 + a[3] (-1 + a[4]) == a[11] && a[3] a[5] == a[12] && 
 a[3] != 0 && a[13] == (a[5] a[11])/a[3] && a[11] != 0 && 
 a[14] == (a[12] a[13])/a[11] && a[10] != 0 && 
 a[15] == (-4 a[4]^2 + 4 a[3] a[5] + a[11]^2)/a[10]
```

I got these by using Reduce on a set of equations and then after that, setting a[0] to be equal to 1. Now I want to expand each of these equations in terms of a[1]; so I want to get a series expansion of a[2], a[3], ..., a[15] in terms of a[1]. I thought that AsymptoticSolve may do the trick, but it did not. My first attempt is this:

```
AsymptoticSolve[results[[1]], {vars}, a1 -> 0];
```

where results[[1]] is the collection of equations shown above and vars is shown below.

```
vars = Array[a, 16, 0];
```

This gave me the error message:

```
"AsymptoticSolve: <<1>> is not a system of equations."
```

I feel like there must be a function dedicated to expanding each variable in terms of other variables using relations such as these, but I can't find any that looks right. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To expand in a power series, use the function `Series`.

Comment: @march I know how to do that if I have each variable explicitly in terms of a[1] already, but my problem is I need to iteratively solve for each variable somehow. Schematically, it would look like the following:

Comment: Solve for a[2] in terms of a[1], then expand in powers of a[2]. Next, solve for a[3] in terms of a[1] and a[2] and use the series expansion of a[2] to get a series expansion for a[3]. Do this process 14 more times and finally get to plugging in the series expansion for each of the other variables to get an expansion for a[15].

Comment: What was the Reduce input?

Comment: @CarlWoll It was a list of 72 homogeneous polynomials all set equal to zero.

Comment: Why did the Reduce output only have 15 variables?

Comment: @CarlWoll The full set of equations has 16 variables (a0, a1, .... , a15) but in the situation I am interested in, the set of 72 equations are highly degenerate and reduce to just 15 (I think) independent equations.

Comment: If you solve the result of Reduce (red), you get the a[2] till a[15] in terms of a[1].  `solRe = Solve[red, Table[a[i], {i, 2, 15}], Reals] ` .  But most of the series expansions of a[j] are not meromorphic at a[1]==0, that means, they can't be expressed with polynomials at zero `Table[Series[Evaluate[a[j] /. solRe], {a[1], 0, 1}] // Normal, {j, 2, 
  15}] `